# Pending changes to an object in child window

Tags: c#

I have a DataGrid that displays an `ObservableCollection<Worker>`. When a cell is double-clicked, a new window is opened that displays data about the selected `Worker` and allows the user to modify certain properties. In this child window are 'Accept' and 'Cancel' buttons. My intent is to have any changes made to `Worker` be temporary until 'Accept' or 'Cancel' is clicked. If 'Accept' is clicked, I'd like to have these changes made permanent and if 'Cancel' is clicked, have them discarded. I haven't yet been able to find a way to do this. When `ExecuteHireCommand` is activaded, the data is sent back to the main project immediately. I need a way to only have the changes made permanent when I click 'Accept'. Any advice you could give would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class WorkerWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Members

    private Worker _worker;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string WindowKey { get; set; }

    public Worker Worker
    {
        get { return _worker; }
        set
        {
            if (_worker == value)
                return;
            _worker = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Worker);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Construction

    public WorkerWindowViewModel()
    {
        CreateCommands();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void CreateCommands()
    {
        HireCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteHireCommand());

        AcceptCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteAcceptCommand());
        CancelCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteCancelCommand());
    }

    #endregion

    #region Commands

    public RelayCommand HireCommand { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand AcceptCommand { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand CancelCommand { get; private set; }

    private void ExecuteHireCommand()
    {
        Worker.IsEmployed = true;
        Worker.Employer = DataManager.Data.MasterGuildList[0];
    }
    private void ExecuteAcceptCommand()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send<Worker>(Worker);

        Messenger.Default.Send<CloseWindowMessage>(new CloseWindowMessage(), WindowKey);
    }

    private void ExecuteCancelCommand()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send<CloseWindowMessage>(new CloseWindowMessage(), WindowKey);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

If it helps, here is how the child window is created.

```
Messenger.Default.Register<OpenWorkerWindowMessage>(this, message =>
        {
            var uniqueKey = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var workerWindowVM = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<WorkerWindowViewModel>(uniqueKey);
            workerWindowVM.Worker = message.Argument;
            workerWindowVM.WindowKey = uniqueKey;
            var workerWindow = new WorkerWindowView(uniqueKey)
            {
                DataContext = workerWindowVM,
                Owner = this
            };
            workerWindow.Closed += (sender, args) => SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister(uniqueKey);
            workerWindow.Show();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The window which opens to edit the selected worker needs to operate on its own *copy* of the worker data, so that the contents of your observable collection is not modified until/unless the accept is clicked - the accept action would update the selected worker in the collection from the "temporary" copy operated on by the "edit worker" window.

Comment: I figured it was something along those lines. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I'm not up on MVVM, so I can't offer any further help, but I do know that the purpose of ObservableCollection is to trigger immediate notification of changes, so you wouldn't want to make discardable updates to its content.

Comment: I'll keep searching. Thanks for your help.